# Pathwise definition of stochastic integral consistent with the Ito isometry

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

My definition of the stochastic integral is that it it is the image of the Ito isometry. Now we also prove Ito's formula and then apply it pathwise and get a pathwise definition in some cases. But in Ito's formula the following definition of the stochastic integral is used:

$$\int_0^t f(X_s) dX_s = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{s \in \pi_n} f(X_s) (X_{s'\wedge t} - X_{s\wedge t})$$

Where $\pi_n$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\text{mesh}(\pi_n) \to 0$ and $s'$ is the successor of $s$ in $\pi_n$.

The right-hand side is the Riemann-sum approximation of the integral. But we only have proven that this converges to the integral in some special cases ($f(X_s)$ continuous and bounded for example). The only condition on $f$ is that it lies in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ here.

I understood that the right-hand-side converges - but why should it converge to the stochastic integral defined by the Ito isometry?

**Edit**: To elaborate on my definition of the stoch. integral: We have defined the stochastic integral for the simple processes $E$ which are of the kind $H := \sum_{i=0}^n 1_{(a_i, a_{i+1}]} A_i$ with $A_i$ being $F_{a_i}$-measureable and bounded. For this kind of processes the stochastic integral is defined as

$$J(H) := \int_0^t H_t dM_t = \sum_{i=0}^n A_i (M_{a_{i+1}} - M_{a_i})$$

Now the ito isometry tells us that $||H||_{L^2(\Omega \times [0, u), \mathbb{P} \times \lambda)} = ||J(H)||_{M^2([0,u))}$ where the hilbert space $M^2([0,u))$ consist of equivalence classes of square-integrable martingales, $M \sim M'$ iff $M$ and $M'$ are modifications of each other, i.e. $\forall t: \mathbb{P}(M_t = M'_t) = 1 $. Now $J$ implies a unique isometry $\overline{J}$ on the closure of $E$ in $L^2(\Omega \times [0, u)$.

$\overline{J}(H)$ for $H \in \overline{E}$ is the stochastic integral.

Comment: What do you mean by "the stochastic integral [...] is the image of the Itô isometry"...? What is the "image of the Itô isometry"...?

Comment: @saz, I now elaborated on how we defined the stochastic integral. I hope it clarifies your question